# How to create an Audio CD using wodim & cue file?

Tags: linux, terminal, audio-recording, cd-burning, cue-sheet

I have problem writing audio CD in my Debian 8.

I have wav file (Duration: 00:04:48.58) and cue file:

```
FILE "out.wav" WAVE
TITLE "Sword"
TRACK 01 AUDIO
  TITLE "One"
  PERFORMER "nt"
  INDEX 01 00:00:00
TRACK 02 AUDIO
  TITLE "Two"
  PERFORMER "nt"
  INDEX 01 01:44:23
```

When I try to run in terminal:

```
wodim dev=/dev/cdrom -pad -audio -dao cuefile=out.cue
```

answer is:

```
wodim: Bad audio track size 32505068 for track 02.
wodim: Audio tracks must be at least 705600 bytes and a multiple of 2352.
wodim: See -pad option.
```

From wodim man :

```
 If the -pad option refers to an audio track, wodim will pad the audio
 data to be a multiple of 2352 bytes.
```

Comment: I haven't used wodim, but try reversing the options to `-audio -pad` because `-pad` does different things with non-audio data tracks.  See the man page for more details.

Comment: **no results....**